# Linux system not booting after chown of the root directory `/`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, permissions, ownership

Recently I was unable to paste a video file from `download` to one of my directories. It was giving error related to permission so I changed the owner of `/` to myself with

```
sudo chown -R pranav .
```

Now it is not booting anymore, and is getting stuck on Ubuntu loading screen. As a beginner to Ubuntu I was just exploring things...

My system has dual boot, with Ubuntu and Win 10.
How to handle this situation?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/987566/693277

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't undo the operation until you know who owned every single file and directory before (users and groups)... Which in general is quite difficult if you think that a Linux installation (home excluded) can get to have millions between files and directories.

How to proceed (make a choice):

1. You can start with a pen drive and save what you think you need (starting from your home). Then reinstall over the system **deleting** the old installation. Then copying back your home. Simply and safe. (Just be careful not to delete/overwrite the windows partition.)
2. The same of point 1 but **without deleting** the previous installation.
   In same cases it can prompt you if you want to keep the old configuration file or not, give it a look check differences decide and how to proceed. Longer, with some risks if it will keep *old* files and directory ownership (the defective ones in this case are the *old* ones).
3. You may do a fresh installation of your OS **on another** disk/partition/computer, check for each file and directory installed and make a script to read their owner and group and save them in a file. Then with another script you can change the files with the same name e path in the damaged system... but you will end up with a system that can be not stable <sup>[[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/987566/196535)]</sup>. Long and risky.
4. You can try to **recover** the system starting with a USB pen drive with the same Linux version and check if it is available some *restore system*  under the advanced option and if it will work.
5. You may start with a USB pen drive go to search for (and save) info about which **packages** were **installed** on your system  <sup>[[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/280843/196535)]</sup>. Backup your home dir (if you want).
   After install the system as new and then use the list of installed packages you saved before.

However, this episode will help you remember that there is a reason why normal users are not **root**, and why the `sudo` command was created to run commands as root just for a limited time. Root is Linux God and can do anything right or wrong. Immediately without confirmation and without appeal. Good luck and keep being curious, but try to be more cautious.

Answer (score -3):

Boot the Ubuntu machine as a single-user mode and change the ownership back provided you know the ownership of the folders and files you have modified..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain a bit.. like to who i should make owner I don't know that part and how do I boot it in a single user mode

Comment: @prnv4907 This -> https://askubuntu.com/a/987566/1210606 and nothing else. This attempt of an answer is simply wrong and should be deleted.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Unfortunately you cannot revert the operation because  you simply do not know which were the ownership of each single file and directory before... (in my laptop Linux installation I have more than 4 Million files... home excluded).

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Can you please help me tacking this situation. Do I need to uninstall Linux and then again install it. I am running it in dual boot mode with win 10 alongside it.

Comment: @prnv4907 If you don't understand the linked Q&A, well, that unfortunate, but hopefully Hastur's answer will clarify it for you.

Comment: @Arjun I see the downvotes. The point is, it doesn't answer how to get your corrupted system back up and running, and may lead the casual reader to think that you can simply undo that command. Which in general and in almost all cases is either impossible to do or very long and risky and of uncertain success. Do not take it personal, [edit] your question or delete it and really welcome on SuperUser.